# CodeIgniter 3: Convert between file and database sessions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

For my app, I would like to offer my users a choice between file-based and database-driven [sessions](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html). I usually use file-based sessions, but over time more users are asking for database-based for a whole host of reasons (mainly file system restrictions on random hosting sites).

However, I'm concerned regarding data persistence. It would be great if there was a straightforward way to convert between the two while preserving user data.

Does CI3 have that function? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: Is your “app” installed in multiple locations, so your “users” are the admins of the installations, or are you talking about individual users? It sounds like the former, but I just want to be clear. I’m not familiar with CI specifically, but isn’t session storage just a config change and is opaque to the system itself?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, it's the former. What they're asking for is on-the-fly conversion between the two, mostly due to live system migration (bare-metal to cloud, or vice versa) and I'm not exactly sure how to approach that.